# Dynamically allocating memory to an array and reading a large text file

Tags: arrays, c, memory, dynamic

I've had a look at some other similar questions and examples but I'm stumped. My goal is to open a very large text file (novel sized), allocate memory to an array, and then store the text into that array so I'm able to do further processing in the future.

This is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINELEN 74

int main(void) {

FILE *file;
char filename[] = "large.txt";
int count = 0, i = 0, len;

/* Open the file */
  file = fopen(filename, "r");
  if (file == NULL) {
      printf("Cannot open file");
      return -1;
  }
    
/* Get size of file for memory allocation */
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    
/* Allocate memory to the array */
  char *text_array = (char*)malloc(size*sizeof(char));
    
/* Store the information into the array */
    while(fgets(&text_array[count], LINELEN, file) != NULL) {
      count++;
      }

  len = sizeof(text_array) / sizeof(text_array[0]);

  while(i<len) {
    /* printf("%s", text_array); */
    i++;
  }
  printf("%s", text_array);

/* return array */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I was expecting to have a large body of text printed from text_array at the bottom. Instead I get a garbled mess of random characters much smaller than the body of text I was hoping for. What am I doing wrong? I suspect it has something to do with my memory allocation but don't know what.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to use `text_array` as if it's a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: Why are you using `fgets()`? Just read the entire file with one call to `fread()`.

Comment: If you are wanting to access each line in the stored file, your other option is to dynamically allocate a pointer for each line and then allocate memory to hold the line read by `fgets()` (don't forget to remove the `'\n'` and add `+1`for the *nul-terminating* character), copy the line to your allocated block and assign the starting address for the block to your pointer. When you need more pointers, `realloc` and keep going. E.g. `char **lines;` and then allocate pointers, `size_t p_avail = 2, p_used = 0; line = malloc (p_avail * sizeof *lines);` Realloc when `p_used == p_avail`.

Comment: That approach is shown here [How to take text file as command line argument in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57488262/3422102) However, if you just want to store the entire file in a single array, then `fread` as @Barmar shows is the best approach. (there is a trick also, allocate `size+1` bytes and set `text_array[size] = 0;` and you can treat the entire thing as a string) Before long -- you'll just be a Penguin...

Comment: What does it mean large? 1MB , 10MB, 1GB, 100GB?

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks for all your help! Sorry it's taken me so long to reply. To answer a few questions this is for an assignment and I'm required to use fgets unfortunately. 

David C. Rankin I'm going to give your solution a go too it seem to achieve what I'm after with fgets. 

Finally by 'large' it's a 6.4MB text file so not huge but a considerable amount of text to handle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to call `fgets()` in a loop. You know how big the file is, just read the entire thing into `text_array` with one call:

```
fread(text_array, 1, size, file);
```

However, if you want to treat `text_array` as a string, you need to add a null terminator. So you should add 1 when calling `malloc()`.

Another problem is `len = sizeof(text_array) / sizeof(text_array[0])`. `text_array` is a pointer, not an array, so you can't use `sizeof` to get the amount of space it uses. But you don't need to do that, since you already have the space in the `size` variable.

There's no need to print `text_array` in a loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LINELEN 74

int main(void) {

    FILE *file;
    char filename[] = "large.txt";
    int count = 0, i = 0, len;

/* Open the file */
    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file");
        return -1;
    }
    
/* Get size of file for memory allocation */
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    
/* Allocate memory to the array */
    char *text_array = (char*)malloc(size*sizeof(char) + 1);
    
/* Store the information into the array */
    fread(text_array, 1, size, file);
    text_array[size] = '\0';
    printf("%s", text_array);

/* return array */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this! That actually clears up everything I didn't understand about what was going on. Very much appreciated.

Comment: I should have mentioned I am required to use fgets but what you've given me does clear up a lot of the questions I've had. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This part

```
while(fgets(&text_array[count], LINELEN, file) != NULL) {
  count++;
}
```

is problematic.

If the loop is un-rolled it's "kind of like":

```
fgets(&text_array[0], LINELEN, file)
fgets(&text_array[1], LINELEN, file)
fgets(&text_array[2], LINELEN, file)
```

So you only advance the `fgets`destination buffer by a single char between each `fgets` call. If we assume the `fgets` reads more than a single character, the second `fgets` overwrites data from the first `fgets`. The third `fgets` overwrites data from the second and so on.

You need to advance the buffer with as many characters as `fgets` actually read or use another way of reading, e.g. `fread`.

Comment: So because each line overwrites most of the last that's why I'm getting a series of random incoherent characters instead of a body of text?

You say that 'If we assume the fgets reads more than a single character". If that's so, and I'm overwriting characters, how do I use fgets to take the whole body of text?

I've tried changing it to:

while(fgets(&text_array[count], 1, file) != NULL) 

thinking it would then read one char at a time and input it into the array but instead I get a segmentation fault but the memory I malloc should be plenty shouldn't it? Thanks for your answer.